# How to reload a parent page on closing a overlay lightbox (wordpress)?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to refresh a parent page when closing a overlay lightbox (not popup window).

The lightbox has no close button, it's closed by clicking anywhere outside the lightbox.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't refresh the parent page.

Would you plase let me know how to refresh the parent page?
HTML:

```
<div class="dwqa-ask-question">
<a href="https://www.myweb.com/ask-questions/" rel="lightbox" data-lightbox-type="iframe">Ask Question
</a>
</div>
```

Lightbox:

```
<div class="nivo-lightbox-overlay nivo-lightbox-theme-default nivo-lightbox-effect-fade nivo-lightbox-open">
    <div class="nivo-lightbox-wrap">
        <div class="nivo-lightbox-content">
        <iframe src="https://www.mycom.com/ask-questions/" class="nivo-lightbox-item" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="nivo-lightbox-title-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-nav nivo-lightbox-prev" style="display: none;">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-nav nivo-lightbox-next" style="display: none;">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-close" title="Close">Close</a>
</div>
```

Added the following code in a lightbox page (=ask-questions page):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.opener) { 
        window.close();
    }
    if (window != top) {
        top.location.replace(document.location);
    }
});
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function refreshParentWindow(){
           window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
           window.top.close();
       });
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
var rel = window.opener.location; 
window.close(); 
rel.reload(); 
});
```

Thank you.

---

"Responsive Lightbox" is the plugin i'm using for the lightbox.

Comment: Hi @isbe! There are several ways that you could write this, it all depends on how you want to set your page up! When your light box shows up, does it have a specific css rule? When your light box opens, how can you detect it? css/html wise. Does it have a specific css/html class/id?

Comment: Hi Ruvee: I hope you are well and safe, long time no see : ) I'm using a plugin (Responsive Lightbox) to open the lightbox. When you add rel="lightbox" data-lightbox-type="iframe" to a button, it opens a lightbox. If you need any other info, please let me know. Thank you for your help all the time Ruvee.

Comment: Thank you! No problem! When the light-box opens up, can you inspect it in your browser and see if the light-box `div` still has the same class as you mentioned in your question? Or there are other classes, in addition to `dwqa-ask-question` class.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: I updated HTML of the lightbox

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to set this up. I personally always use additional css classes to show and/or hide my html elements on the page, but since you're currently using a plugin, then you could add an event listener to your page.

So use this javascript on your page:

```js
jQuery(document).ready($ => {

  console.log("You just loaded your js file onto the page"); // Testing whether you've loaded your js file correctly!

  $(document).on("click", e => {
    if (
      document.querySelector('.nivo-lightbox-overlay').contains(e.target)
      &&
      !document.querySelector(".nivo-lightbox-wrap").contains(e.target)
     ) {
      console.log("You just clicked outside of the lightbox wrap"); // Testing event listener

      location.reload(); // a simple refresh
      // OR 
      // location.reload(true); // a hard refresh
    };
  });
});
```

You see the `orange` area around your light-box wrap with `nivo-lightbox-overlay` class? Click anywhere on it an it'll reload your page!

[image]

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

---

**Another solution**

```js
jQuery(document).ready( $ => {
    $(document).on("click", "div.nivo-lightbox-overlay", () => {

        if ($("div.nivo-lightbox-overlay").length) {

          location.reload(); // a simple refresh
          // OR 
          // location.reload(true); // a hard refresh

        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ruvee. I tried the code using both .nivo-lightbox-overlay  and .nivo-lightbox-wrap. But it doesn't refresh the parent page. Would you please let me know whatelese I can try?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Please give it a try!

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thanks again for your help. I pasted the code in my lightbox page, but it still doesn't refresh the pargent page. Console shows no error, so I'm not sure how to edit it.. Could you please help me again.. Sorry...

Comment: Hmmmm interesting! Well i installed `Responsive Lightbox Lite` plugin and created exactly the same html link structure as you did. The javascript snippet that i provided you with is working fine on my end. Are you sure that it doesn't reload your page? Because it reloads fast you might not even realize it! Try to put a console log before the `reload` function to see the console massage. `console.log("You just clicked outside of the lightbox wrap");`

Comment: Also make sure that you're loading your javascript file onto the page correctly! It's working fine on my end. I just updated my answer with `debugging` lines. try it and watch your console for the messages. You should be able to see both messages.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: How are you? Thanks again for your help : ) I put the code in a lightbox page. This time the console shows one error: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I can't see You just clicked outside of the lightbox wrap in the console.  I'm sorry but would you please let me know what would be the problem?

Comment: Sure, no problem! Did you make sure that your `javascript` file is loaded? Did you see "You just loaded your js file onto the page" message in your console when you first load the page?

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thank you for your supportive hlep : ). I removed ; from }; and now console shows no error. I've checked the message while opening the lightbox and the console shows like thes => https://i.imgur.com/Tpci0CY.jpg . After I close the lightbox, it doesn't refresh the parent page, and console is not showing You just clicked outside of the lightbox wrap. Would you please let me know what action I should take? Thanks again Ruvee.

Comment: @isbe Just added another solution for you! Please give it a try an let me know if you were able to get it to work! Both solutions are now working on my end!

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thanks again : ) Would you please confirm if I took correct action? 1. I added the code on a lightbox page using a custom JS widget of Elementor (https://i.imgur.com/dvCq9kC.jpg). 2. I opened the parent page 3. I clicked the button 4. The lightbox opened 5. I closed the lightbox by clicking on the lightbox overlay button. I took the above action but, it still doesn't refresh the pargent page. I also tested it on another test domain, and it still doesn't refresh the parent page... I'm not sure why it just doesn't work when I'm doing it...

Comment: I think i know where the issue is! Would you please confirm **the exact name of the plugin** you're using? Is it "Responsive Lightbox" or is it "Responsive Lightbox & Gallery"?

Comment: Hi Ruvee: It's Responsive Lightbox. I really thank you for your help Ruvee : )

Comment: No problem! Is it possible to take a screen shot of the light-box when it's open and share it too?

Comment: Yep, lightbox is :https://i.imgur.com/Wjq60ix.jpg.  And plugin is this one : https://www.webstudioq.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=responsive-lightbox-lite&TB_iframe=true&width=772&height=757

Comment: Yes that's the exact plugin i installed on my machine! And it's odd that both solutions are working on my end when i click on the dark area around the box . It could be the "jquery". Do you have "jquery" loaded onto the page?

Comment: Hi Ruvee: When I check the console of the lightbox, it shows 'You just loaded your js file onto the page'. I think it loaded the code. But, I can't see 'You just clicked outside of the lightbox wrap' after closing the lightbox by clicking the dark area. I thought my domain had problems so I used another test domain, but it still doesn't refresh... Hmmm, I also not sure why it's not working when I'm doing it...

Comment: Thanks for responding. Honestly, it's super odd to me, because i installed the exact plugin as you did and created the exact html structure as you did and tested both snippets that i provided above and both are working. The only thing that i can think of now is the browser. I have tested both `firefox` and `chrome` and they both worked fine on my end.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: yeah, that's really strange... I also use chrome .... I'm sorry ...